# How to save the session even after the browser close Javascript

Tags: javascript, session

Is it possible to save the login data even after the browser close. When I open the page and hit the URL, it has to open the page directly.

If possible could you please provide me any references in JavaScript..

Thanks,

Comment: you can use localStorage to store username but storing password is not right

Comment: Also, to be honest this can be achieved using any number of password extensions in browsers (or within the browsers themselves). Doing it yourself is asking for trouble and won't be secure at all.

Answer (score 0):

**This is just a suggestion, there is a lot of way to achieve this:**

You could store the credentials in a Database and check if they are valid with **`passport.js`**. To keep your session logged in, you can use **`express-session`** (https://github.com/expressjs/session) which is a module of **`node.js`** and connect the session to your database via a 'Compatible Session Stores' ( you can find the list of all the stores at the end of the previous url). This will store a cookie and keep your session alive.